# Creating Fake for class that uses Prism and requests events with ThreadOption.UIThread

Tags: unit-testing, prism, microsoft-fakes

We're in the process of moving from Prism 4.1 to 5.  One item that has popped up is we create a Stub EventAggregator (Microsoft Fakes) for our unit test.  The EventAggregator gets set in the target class and some subscribers get set with

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<RangeChangedEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateDisplay,
                    ThreadOption.UIThread,
                    false,
                    args => args.ID == ID);
```

The unit test worked fine with Prism 4.1.  But, now I get this exception in Prism 5 when running my unit test.

> System.InvalidOperationException: To use the UIThread option for subscribing, the EventAggregator must be constructed on the UI thread..

So, is there a way to get a reference to what Prism thinks is the UI thread?  Or a way to tell prism the unit test thread is the UI thread?  Or do I need to subscribe on the publishing thread and test the Dispatcher in the "UpdateDisplay" method?

Thanks.

Comment: Working with xUnit here... And so far no luck, had to use a Mocked service, which uses Dispatcher in the current App, allowing me to remove `ThreadOption.UIThread` and still launch my method on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nunit you can decorate your test fixture class with the RequiresSTA attribute and this will make testrunner use the UI thread and hopefully it should resolve the problem for you.